# How to remove the header of MyToolkit Datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am using MyToolkit DataGrid in my windows app found here https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid. I want to remove the header from the datagrid. How can I do this?
Can Any one tell me...
Thanks In advance.

Here is my code

```
        <controls:DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </controls:DataGrid.RowStyle>

        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>

            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SNumber}" Width="0.5*" CanSort="False" Foreground="White">
                <!--<controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Button x:Name="btnSl" x:Uid="RSNO" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Background="DarkTurquoise" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></Button>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>-->
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
            </controls:DataGridTextColumn>

            <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource myCellTemplateMonth}"  Width="2.5*" x:Name="ItemDesc"  CanSort="False" IsAscendingDefault="True">

            </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding uom}" Width="0.5*" CanSort="False" Foreground="White">
                <!--<controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Button x:Name="btnUOM" x:Uid="uom" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Grid.Column="2" Background="DarkTurquoise"></Button>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>-->
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
            </controls:DataGridTextColumn>

            <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="0.7*" CanSort="False">
                <!--<controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Button x:Name="bPrice" x:Uid="ItemPrice" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Grid.Column="3" Background="DarkTurquoise"></Button>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>-->
                <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="pricePanel"  Height="30" Tapped="pricePanel_Tapped" >
                            <TextBlock Name="price" Foreground="White"  Text='{Binding editedPrice}' TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="0.7*" CanSort="False">

                <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="quantityPanel"  Height="30" Tapped="quantityPanel_Tapped">
                            <TextBlock Name="quantity" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"  Text='{Binding quantity}' VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="0.6*" CanSort="False">
                <!--<controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Button x:Name="btnDiscnt" x:Uid="Rdiscount" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Grid.Column="5" Background="DarkTurquoise" ></Button>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>-->
                <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="discountPanel"  Height="30" Tapped="discountPanel_Tapped" >
                            <TextBlock Name="Discount" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text='{Binding discount}' VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>

            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cartTotal}" Width="0.85*" CanSort="False" Foreground="White">
                <!--<controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Button x:Name="btnCost" x:Uid="ItemCost" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Grid.Column="6" Background="DarkTurquoise"></Button>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Header>-->
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-40,0,0,0"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.Style>
            </controls:DataGridTextColumn>

            <!--delete image column-->
            <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn CanSort="False">
                <!--<controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>
                    <Image Source="/Images/erase.png" Height="40" Width="40" Grid.Column="7" Margin="5"></Image>
                </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.Header>-->
                <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="voidImagePanel"  Height="30" Tapped="voidImagePanel_Tapped">
                            <Image x:Name="VoidImage" Source="/Images/delete.png" Height="20" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="-20,5,0,0"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
            </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>


        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

here I dont want the header. but I am getting empty space. how can I remove that.[image]

Comment: Can you please post your actual code? We don't link to our code or post images. We need actual code to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> here I don't want the header. but I am getting empty space. how can I remove that.

I have checked the source code of MyToolkit, the only way is to modify the default template for DataGrid and set the `ColumnHeaders` element's `Visibility` property to `Collapsed`:

- Firstly, adding these two xaml prefixes:

  `xmlns:controls="using:MyToolkit.Controls"
  xmlns:Converters="using:MyToolkit.Converters"`
- Secondly, appending the following style and assign to DataGrid:

  ```
  <controls:DataGrid.Resources>
          <Converters:VisibilityConverter x:Key="vc" />

          <Converters:NotConverter x:Key="nc" />

          <!-- TransparentListBox -->
          <Style x:Key="TransparentListBox" TargetType="ListBox">
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
              <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxBorderThemeThickness}"/>
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
              <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
              <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
              <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
              <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
              <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                          <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                          <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                          <Storyboard>
                                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                          </Storyboard>
                                      </VisualState>
                                  </VisualStateGroup>
                                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                  </VisualStateGroup>
                              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                              <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" 
                                HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" 
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" 
                                IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" 
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" 
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" 
                                ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                                  <ItemsPresenter/>
                              </ScrollViewer>
                          </Border>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
          </Style>

          <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="controls:DataGrid">
              <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
              <Setter Property="HeaderBackground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeHighBrush}" />
              <Setter Property="RowBackgroundOddBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}" />
              <Setter Property="CellTemplate">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <ContentPresenter Margin="12" Content="{Binding Control}" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:DataGrid">
                          <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                              </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                              <Grid Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="{TemplateBinding HeaderBackground}" Height="40" x:Name="ColumnHeaders">
                                  <!-- HACK: Needed so that column DPs are working when adding columns in code only. -->
                                  <ContentPresenter>
                                      <controls:DataGridTextColumn />
                                  </ContentPresenter>
                              </Grid>

                              <controls:MtListBox BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1"
                                      ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding RowStyle}"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource TransparentListBox}" 
                                      Margin="0" x:Name="Rows" />
                          </Grid>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
              <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <Grid Background="Transparent">
                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                              <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                      Margin="12,0,12,2" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}" 
                                      Content="{Binding Header}" />

                              <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" 
                                      Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource vc}}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                  <Path Data="M4,0 L0,8 L8,8 Z" Fill="White" Visibility="{Binding IsAscending, Converter={StaticResource vc}}"/>
                                  <Path Data="M0,0 L4,8 L8,0 Z" Fill="White" Visibility="{Binding IsAscending, Converter={StaticResource nc}}"/>
                              </StackPanel>
                          </Grid>
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
          </Style>
      </controls:DataGrid.Resources>
      <controls:DataGrid.Style>
          <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridStyle1"/>
      </controls:DataGrid.Style>
  ```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Check my completed demo [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/MyToolkitDataGridUWPApp1)**